# Dynamic E-tags handler

Tags: symfony, caching

I came up with this idea about caching my symfony2 dynamic pages.
I have a kind of wall where other usesrs posts are displayed.
I want to cache this wall for every user until one of the users he follows post something.
Here is the approach I designed, but it has one problem:
I add a field for each user in the database called E-tag, let's say a user has this etag value  : X3FR
 
As long as no user he follows post anything new the etag remains the same and the page is displayed from cache (varnish or nginx).
when a user post something I update the etag to some random stuff so there will be no HITS when looking for cache, and new content is displayed from server. 
My only problem is that the etag that will be tested will also be cached and I'll end up with the same page all the time.

```
No new posts -> read etag -> find cache by etag
new post -> update etag -> no cache hits -> fresh content
```

How can I not cache the etag retrieved from database?
I heard something about ESI, that it caches fragments. can it work in this case ?

Comment: That's a brilliant approach! I'm interested into what this discussion would turn out to.